Why console displays modified data?
I'm testing the webRequest API for extension. Specifically, I want to modify the data in the request body before sending it to the server
I think the console log would display the data before the modification, i.e., "test", but it actually displays the modified data "hello world", why?
manifest.json
{
  "description": "Demonstrating webRequests",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "webRequest-demo",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://localhost/*"],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}

background.js
function changebody(requestDetails) {
    if(requestDetails.method=="POST") {
        console.log("requestDetails:", requestDetails);
        requestDetails.requestBody.formData["textarea1"]=["hello world"];
    }
    return  requestDetails;

}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  changebody,
  { urls: ["*://localhost/*"]},
  ["blocking","requestBody"],
);

<html>
<head><title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="test.php" method="post">
    <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1">test</textarea>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>

